# Recording failed HTTP requests with tcpdump

Tags: java, tomcat, wireshark, tcpdump

I have Java webapp running inside Tomcat 7.0.22, from time to time there are HTTP requests that cause `HTTP 500` (Unexpected exceptions in my app) in production env. In order to reproduce those errors in a staging environment I'd usually run `tcpdump` and record all HTTP traffic and then use WireShark to filter packets with `http.response.code != 200 or 204 or 302` and run "follow HTTP stream" on each response, thus giving me the request that caused this error. Then I can rerun this request with cURL on the staging environment.

My question is:

- How can this procedure be done automatically?
- Is there a way to achieve the same effect (to reproduce errors) with some other technique? (maybe some `Filter` inside Tomcat)

Thanks

Alex

Comment: But why don't you do something simple like logging the requests in prod env?

Comment: I want it to be transparent. I haven't found a nice way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tools that provide such functionality. Actually they even do more: they typically instrument your java code so that can detect which module is responsible on the failure.

I personally was working for company named [Correlsense](http://www.correlsense.com/) that implements such solution. It is commercial, but your can start from evaluation version that is distributed for free and can be downloaded from the we site. Alternatively I can offer you to check out [newrelic.com](http://newrelic.com/) that looks better than Correlsense although I personally have not used it but only tried to play a little bit.

Comment: Thank, Actually we have a newRelic license, I check this feature out. Do you, by chance, know how it is implemented in newRelic. Because there's a not-so-good solution with Tomcat filter which consumes the input stream thus able to dump ip.